# How I can add an adjacency list to a node of defined type in C?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a defined node type for graph node:

```
    struct node{
    int data;
    int neighboursNumber;
    node * neighbours;
    };
```

And I am trying to add for each node some neighbours like this:

```
    node * n1 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n1->data = 1;
    n1->neighboursNumber = 2;
    n1->neighbours = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node) * n1->neighboursNumber);

    node * n2 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n2->data = 2;
    n2->neighboursNumber = 1;
    n2->neighbours = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node) * n2->neighboursNumber);

    node * n3 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n3->data = 3;
    n3->neighboursNumber = 1;
    n3->neighbours = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node) * n3->neighboursNumber);

    n1->neighbours[0] = n2;
    n1->neighbours[1] = n3;

    n2->neighbours[0] = n1;
    n3->neighbours[0] = n1;
```

But I get an error at building

```
 error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand 
 of type 'node *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Isn't that the correct way to do it?

Comment: [Casting the result of malloc is pointless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Your `neighbours` should probably be `node **`, rather than `node*`.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Add the line `struct node;` before the actual structure definition so that the compiler knows what the `neighbours` field is supposed to point to. It's called a forward declaration.

Comment: Also, write yourself a `create_node` function which takes the values for `data` and `neighboursNumber` as arguments and returns a properly constructed `node` object.

Comment: At first glance I would ask why do you do `n1->neighbours = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node) * n1->neighboursNumber);`?  The subsequent `n1->neighbours[0] = n2;` is a memory leak... ?

Comment: I do `n1->neighbours = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node) *n1->neighboursNumber);` because I need to dinamically allocate memory for the neighbours array.

Comment: pedward is right. You first allocate memory and then just overwrite pointer to it so it will never be freed.

Comment: And how is the proper way to do it?

Comment: `node * n2 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));` does the allocation of the neighbour.  The struct node definition should use `node ** neighbours;` so that you can then malloc and free units of `sizeof(node *)` to save a pointer for your neighbours.  Clear as mud?  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(borrowing) I think this will work for you...

```
typedef struct _node {
    int    data;
    int    neighboursNumber;
    struct _node **neighbours;
} node;

int main( void ) {

node *n1 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
n1->data = 1;
n1->neighboursNumber = 2;
n1->neighbours = (node **)malloc(sizeof(node *) * n1->neighboursNumber);

node * n2 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
n2->data = 2;
n2->neighboursNumber = 1;
n2->neighbours = (node **)malloc(sizeof(node *) * n2->neighboursNumber);

node * n3 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
n3->data = 3;
n3->neighboursNumber = 1;
n3->neighbours = (node **)malloc(sizeof(node *) * n3->neighboursNumber);
```

Up to here that is...  I am not sure how you are using it but, I don't think your neighbours are aligned in a logical sense...  ??

```
n1->neighbours[0] = n2;
n1->neighbours[1] = n3;

n2->neighbours[0] = n1;
n3->neighbours[0] = n1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
struct node{
int data;
int neighboursNumber;
node * neighbours;
};
```

write this:

```
typedef struct _node{
int data;
int neighboursNumber;
struct _node * neighbours;
} node;
```

but as others have pointed out in the comments, neighbours should rather be

```
struct _node ** neighbors;
```